# Windows 10 driver no longer allows screen to work

Tags: windows-10, display-driver

I just built myself a windows machine, and after I shut it down after the first connection to the internet the screen no longer worked. I turned on narrator and I know the computer is still working, but I am unsure how to fix the screen. I made sure my graphics card was in securely and that the cable connecting the screen was attached and I even tried using a different screen. I believe the issue to be due to a screen driver that got downloaded, but I am essentially navigating blind. Do you have any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: What model is your computer?

Comment: I built it myself, but the graphics card is a GForce GTX 760

Comment: Did you try starting it in safe mode?

Comment: I have zero problems with my own GTX 770 on Windows 10.  I am using the drivers offered by Windows Update even.  Something else is going on, and I can almost guarantee the problem, is not Windows 10.  If you fail to boot into Windows 10, three times, you are offered the advanced Startup menu.  You can use that to boot into Safe Mode.

Comment: It boots up fine, and I can navigate around in windows using narrator, but the screen doesn't work, and its not the connection.

Comment: @Hovestar:  Would you care to clarify why you ask a question and then refuse to troubleshoot it?  If you don't attempt to boot in safe mode and provide the result here, this will make your question unanswerable and therefore off-topic.

Comment: @Hovestar - You need to try Safe Mode.  If you are not willing to do that basic troubleshooting step, then this question isn't that helpful, due to it being currently a question that cannot be answered.

Comment: @Ramhound I just tried and I was unable to get any information from Safe mode. I think I booted into it, but I don't have a screen to confirm, and I couldn't get narrator to work there. I used the hold shift and restart method to try to get into it.

Comment: You have tried a different cable and/or a different monitor?  If you boot into the UEFI shell do you have a display?  If you connect the display directly to the motherboard instead of the external GPU does anything change?

Comment: I did try that. I just moved it upstairs again to connect it to ethernet(I didn't plan on having it networked much) and it worked. I assume then it's just a loose connection on the inside. I'll open it up and check. Thank you so much for your help though!!